# How to display an image in Dialog using Glide?

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso, android-glide

in my app there is an dialog with an image on it.
How can I display an image using glide?

Here is what I tried in my Fragment:

```
    RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.goldversiondialog)
            .error(R.drawable.goldversiondialog);


    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(myURL).apply(options).into(goldimageview);
```

It is not working, it only displays the error image.
I also don't know what to write as context, "this" is not working in fragments.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you add INTERNET permission to your Manifest? (in case `myURL` is a link)

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen Yes I did

Comment: Do you have any error logcat?

Comment: replace http with https

Comment: I suggest you set a `RequestListener` to catch the `onLoadFail` callback and check the `GlideException` passed to it to know exactly where the error comes from

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh That worked!! Thank you. Please write an answer so i can accept it